# how to check if unique_ptr points to the same object as iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, unique-ptr

Let's consider such method:

```
void World::remove_organism(organism_iterator organism_to_delete)
{
    remove_if(begin(organisms_vector), end(organisms_vector), [](const unique_ptr<Organism>& potential_organism_to_del)
        {

        });
}
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to delete organism that `iterator` points to from `vector<unique_ptr<Organism>>`, so how am I supposed to compare `unique_ptr<Organism>` to `std::vector<unique_ptr<Organism>>::iterator`?

Comment: `unique_ptr` values are unique, so the only way "points to the same object" is possible is if you have two references to the same `unique_ptr`.  That said, it may be easier to compare the held pointer anyway.... simply call `get()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you show me exact line of code how to do it?

Comment: `return potential_organism_to_del.get() == organism_to_delete->get();`.. but also, if you're deleting an element the iterator points to, why not just call `vector::erase(iterator)` since you know it's already existing in that container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to search through the `vector` to find an iterator; you just have to erase it:

```
void World::remove_organism(organism_iterator organism_to_delete)
{
    organism_vector.erase(organism_to_delete);
}
```

Or if you want to delete only the element that the `unique_ptr` points to:

```
void World::remove_organism(organism_iterator organism_to_delete)
{
    organism_to_delete->reset();
}
```

Comment: Exactly. `std::vector` has random access iterators. No need to iterate through the vector to find the desired element.

Comment: @digito_evo: It doesn't really have anything to do with whether the iterators are random access or bidirectional or forward-only.  Every kind of iterator gives cheap access to the object at the indicated location, without that it would not be an iterator.

Comment: `organism_to_delete->reset();` will destroy the `Organism` being pointed to, and set the `unique_ptr` to hold `nullptr`, but will not remove the `unique_ptr` from the `vector`